# MVC Web API Post Does not get called from HttpClient

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Model

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The following WebAPI Method

```
    [Route("PostCustomer")]
    [HttpPost]
    public Customer PostCustomer([FromBody]Customer c)
    {
        return c;
    }
```

The following client code

```
Customer cust = new Customer() { Name = "abcd", Address = "test" };
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:11581");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<Customer>("api/values/PostCustomer", cust);
```

The WebAPI Method never gets called and the response I get from the Web API says no content.  When I try the same for a get it works fine.

Comment: Is the client a Windows Store app?

Comment: Nope just a console application.